# Why does Molly Weasley remember a different gamekeeper?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Goblet of Fire*, when Molly and Billy Weasley come to visit Harry before the Third Task, Molly talks about Hagrid’s predecessor.

> Mrs. Weasley was intrigued by the Whomping Willow, which had been planted after she had left school, and reminisced at length about the gamekeeper before Hagrid, a man called Ogg.
>
> — *Goblet of Fire*, chapter 31 (*The Third Task*)

But wouldn’t Hagrid have been gamekeeper when she was in school?

Hagrid was kicked out at 13 around 1943 and began training as gamekeeper. Molly would have arrived at Hogwarts in the early 60s when Hagrid would have been 30. Even if he was still in training or assistant gamekeeper, he would definitely still be there with Ogg. And as Ogg is described as the gamekeeper before Hagrid, that seems to imply that they weren't there together in Molly's memory. How does that work?

Comment: I am just having trouble understanding how in the world you notice something like this. Not sure whether I should be awed or in fear :P

Comment: @DavidMulder - it came up in discussion in comments on prior question :)

Comment: Out-of-universe, could this have been meant as a reference to Pratchett's [Nanny Ogg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanny_Ogg) or one of her relatives?

Comment: @DVK Haha I never even knew this came up somewhere else. I am just way too obsessed with Harry Potter, I listen to the audiobooks like other people listen to music.

Comment: @SQB, no no no, Pratchett stole it from Rowling of course, with the same time machine he used to steal Ponder Stibbons. Thought it was common knowledge ;)

Comment: What is in that passage that implies Molly would not be familiar with Hagrid? Let's assume Hagrid was present as an assistant to Ogg. Why wouldn't Molly reminisce about Ogg with Harry, who is very familiar with Hagrid but unfamiliar with Ogg?

Comment: "Hagrid was kicked out at 13 around 1943" any sources? I will be amazed if this is true. This means by 1997 Hagrid was 67? Not to mention you-know-who.

Comment: @Krumia: Books take place in 1991–8. In *Chamber of Secrets*, we learn that Hagrid was expelled toward the end of his third year. That took place fifty years before the events of *Chamber*, thus Hagrid was expelled in 1943 at age 13.

Comment: The passage doesn't say "gamekeeper _instead_ of Hagrid". Nor it says that Molly doesn't remember Hagrid. So probably, as Alexwlchan explained, they were both there and Hagrid was Ogg's assistant.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

**There is no canon answer.**

As far as I know, Ogg has never been mentioned anywhere by J.K. Rowling anywhere except in that single passage. So I’ll have a guess.

It seems likely that Hagrid was not the sole gamekeeper immediately after his expulsion. That would be too much responsibility for a teenager, and would probably be politically difficult for Dumbledore and Dippet, given Hagrid was just expelled. So he must have served as the assistant to the main gamekeeper, who we can assume to be Ogg.

So why did Ogg stick around for at least twenty years, and why would Molly describe him as Hagrid’s predecessor?

Presumably between starting as assistant gamekeeper, and Molly arriving at the school, Hagrid became old, mature and responsible enough to handle the post by himself. But Dumbledore wouldn’t force Ogg out just because Hagrid is capable of doing without him. If Ogg had nowhere else to go (cf. Professor Trelawney in *Order of the Phoenix*), then  I think it’s very possible that neither Dumbledore nor Dippet would force him to leave.

This means that when Molly joins the school, both Ogg and Hagrid are there, but there’s still a clear division of responsibility and labour. Molly sees Ogg as the (head) gamekeeper, above Hagrid, and Hagrid becomes the (head) gamekeeper after Ogg retires.

Ergo, **Ogg is Hagrid’s predecessor to the position of *head* gamekeeper.**

Molly’s wording is a little ambiguous, but I think that’s how we resolve it.

Comment: Sounds fair enough for me...

Comment: its funny that we can assume that hagrid is close to 70 years old at the time harry was at school, as well as Voldemort being 70 as well. so by the time molly was at school hagrid may have already been close to 30.

Comment: There are many alternative possible explanations we could invent, especially less boring ones, such as "Dumbledore fired everybody and replaced them with his own crew, while the book fails to mention any of this, because it consistently presents a one-sided view, neglecting to mention any of Voldemort's virtues or Dumbledore's evil side".

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev: Deathly Hallows mentions enough things evil about Dumbledoor to make our jaws drop.

Comment: @Krumia That's right, he's a bit of a careerist, isn't he?

Comment: Yeah...out-of-universe, it's pretty obvious this was a mistake.

Comment: @PaulDraper Yes, but where’s the fun in saying that?

Comment: Hmm, I've always wondered whether Nicolas Flamel _really_ didn't want his stone back...

Comment: I wonder if Voldemort stayed the same age when he "died"? That would explain why he's still relatively physically fit and doesn't look like he's 70. As for Hagrid, I'm guessing giants age even slower than wizards.

Comment: An alternative explanation is that Hagrid had a different job prior to becoming Gamekeeper, after Ogg retired, after Molly left. We saw Snape transfer to the DADA position from potions, so we know faculty can change jobs. We also saw Hagrid absorb the magical creatures job into his list, so this is plausible.

Comment: I wonder if there's any Harry Potter fan fiction about Ogg? :-)

Comment: @evgeni - Dumbledore may have an evil side, but Voldemort's virtues? I don't think he has any.

Comment: @Adamant Well, he did do great things. Terrible, but great.

Answer (score 8):

**Based on current information Molly was at school while Ogg was still groundskeeper.**

Hagrid likely did not become the groundskeeper until Dumbledore became Headmaster [which was around 1964/5](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59415/in-which-year-did-dumbledore-become-headmaster). Dumbledore would not have been able to appoint staff members until this time.

I don't think we know what year Molly was born, but we know that Arthur was born [in 1950](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/arthur-weasley) and they attended Hogwarts together, which puts them in school (1961 at the earliest) while Ogg is still groundskeeper for at least a few years.