# Was Quirrell a willing host?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

Can it be inferred from canon whether Quirrell was a willing host to Voldemort?
Was he a supporter of him before he became his host?

If he was tricked, for example, by meeting a weakened, ghostly form of Voldemort who promised great reward for helping, and then afterwards he was just forced to do all the evil he did, I would not count it as being a willing host.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**TL;DR:** No, he was not a willing host, BUT the ground was definitely there to enable him to be possessed (in other words, he had it comin').

> "I saw Quirrell as a gifted but delicate boy, who would probably have been teased for his timidity and nerves during his school life. Feeling inadequate and wishing to prove himself, he developed an (initially theoretical) interest in the Dark Arts. Like many people who feel themselves to be insignificant, even laughable, Quirrell had a latent desire to make the world sit up and notice him." *(from JK Rowling on Quirrel in [Pottermore, Chapter 8](http://pottermore.wikia.com/wiki/Professor_Quirrell)).*

Pottermore elaborates on that in Chapter 17:

> **Quirrell set out deliberately to find whatever remained of the Dark wizard, partly out of curiosity, partly out of that unacknowledged desire for importance. At the very least, Quirrell fantasised that he could be the man who tracked Voldemort down, but at best, might learn skills from Voldemort that would ensure he was never laughed at again**.
>
> Though Hagrid was correct in saying that Quirrell had a ‘brilliant mind,’ the Hogwarts teacher was both naive and arrogant in thinking that he would be able to control an encounter with Voldemort, even in the Dark wizard's weakened state. **When Voldemort realised that the young man had a position at Hogwarts, he took immediate possession of Quirrell, who was incapable of resisting**.
>
> While Quirrell did not lose his soul, he became completely subjugated by Voldemort, who caused a frightful mutation of Quirrell's body: now Voldemort looked out of the back of Quirrell's head and directed his movements, even forcing him to attempt murder. **Quirrell tried to put up feeble resistance on occasion, but Voldemort was far too strong for him**.

Comment: The wiki says "*However, Voldemort, after finding out that he taught at Hogwarts, took over his body, **though Quirrell put up some feeble resistance***"...; http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Quirinus_Quirrell

Comment: @DVK: Don't stop posting them. Posting early has probably won you all the votes here.  People always view threads only once, sort by votes, and read only the top answer, so I'll never catch up.  That's why I'm leading in the other thread: I posted my reply before Slytherincess.

Comment: @DVK, didn't Molde Volde take possesion of Quirrell after he failed to get the stone from the bank? That was why he could shake harry's hand; wasnt it?

Answer (score 10):

I think Quirrel was a willing host.  At his meeting with the weakened Dark Lord, he got genuinely convinced and went to the dark side.  This is evidenced by his monologue in *Philosopher's Stone* chapter 17.

> ‘I met him [Voldemort] when I travelled around the world. A foolish young man I was then, full of riddiculous ideas about good and evil. Lord Voldemort showed me how wrong I was. There is no good and evil, there is only power, and those too weak to seek it … Since then, I have served him faithfully, […]

Comment: I'm not sure that this isn't Voldemort's mind control/brainwashing speaking. JKR wasn't very clear here

Answer (score 1):

[Wizarding World](https://www.wizardingworld.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/professor-quirrell) says that Quirrell was possessed the whole time and tried to resist, but that's completely wrong.

In the book, it says that Quirrell got possessed after he failed to steal the stone from Gringotts, meaning he joined him out of his own free will.

> Quirrell shivered suddenly. 'He does not forgive mistakes easily. When I failed to steal the Stone from Gringotts, he was most displeased. He punished me... decided he would have to **keep a closer watch on me**'

When Harry first met Quirrell, he wore no turban. He started wearing it when he returned to Hogwarts, something Harry noticed after his Sorting Ceremony.

> Harry spotted Professor Quirrell, too, the nervous young man from the Leaky Cauldron. He was looking very peculiar in a large purple turban.

Now, back to the question. Voldemort definitely forced his way in Quirrell's body (I don't think Quirrell liked it), but he wouldn't try to resist, because he was his servant.